# Parsing JSONArray into TextView

Tags: android, arrays

Can someone help guide me on how to parse JSONArray's into TextViews? So far, everytime I parse it, It only shows me the last results, instead of everything.

So far I have:

```
            try {
            standby_position = json.getString("standby_position");
            zone_name = json.getString("zone_name");
            zone_no = json.getString("zone_no");
            status = json.getString("status");


            JSONArray standby_list = json.getJSONArray("standby_list");

            for (int i1 = 0; i1 < standby_list.length(); i1++) {
                JSONObject c = standby_list.getJSONObject(i1);


            DRIVER = c.getString(driver);
            SINCE = c.getString(since);
            WAITING = c.getString(waiting);
            GPS_DATA = c.getString(gps_data);



            }

        } catch (JSONException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I was trying to to do:

```
 TextView information = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.information);
  information.setText ( DRIVER + SINCE + WAITING );
```

Here is what I am trying to parse:

```
 {
"driver": "819",
"gps_data": "1",
"last_geocode": "",
"lastLatitudeUpdate": "12/31/1969 5:00:00 PM",
"standby_position": "1",
"zone_name": "STK",
"zone_no": "STK",
"status": "Your are checked-in and currently #1 STK. (as of: 7/19/2012 1:50:02 PM)",
"standby_list": [
    {
        "driver": "291",
        "since": "12:33:00 PM",
        "waiting": "77",
        "gps_data": "0"
    },
    {
        "driver": "103",
        "since": "12:49:21 PM",
        "waiting": "61",
        "gps_data": "0"
    },
    {
        "driver": "287",
        "since": "12:51:00 PM",
        "waiting": "59",
        "gps_data": "0"
    },
    {
        "driver": "271",
        "since": "1:22:00 PM",
        "waiting": "28",
        "gps_data": "0"
    },
    {
        "driver": "819",
        "since": "8:58:36 AM",
        "waiting": "292",
        "gps_data": "1"
    }
]
 }
```

When I do this, the only last parse Json will show. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by last JSON?

Are you referring to the last object in the JSONArray called "standby_list"?

If so, that's because you are only keeping a handle on the last one.
Instead you should use some sort of collection and be calling Add on that.

For example

```
class MyObject {
    public String driver, since, waiting, gps;
}

List<MyObject> list = new ArrayList<MyObject>();

for (int i1 = 0; i1 < standby_list.length(); i1++) {
    JSONObject c = standby_list.getJSONObject(i1);
    MyObject myContainer = new MyObject();   

    myContainer.driver = c.getString(driver);
    myContainer.since = c.getString(since);
    myContainer.waiting = c.getString(waiting);
    myContainer.gps = c.getString(gps_data);
    list.add(myContainer);
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply Frank, and I think you may be on to something, but How would I place this in TextView instead of ArrayList?

Comment: Well you will have to pick 1 item from your ArrayList to populate your TextViews. If you are trying to display ALL the objects on the screen, then you probably will want to use a ListView. Then you pass your ArrayList into your ListViewAdapter and that will take care of displaying each one. However, that is an entirely different topic.

Answer (score 0):

You get the values in a loop but you are alimenting only one zone. Of course the last zone is the only one to be shown.
Try using a text view for every element of the list or "Toast.makeText(...)" if all you need is to view the values for a limited time.

Answer (score 0):

You always rewrite this variables. That is why you always have only last json